# Firebase Multipath Fetch Data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently, Firebase supports multipath data updates for a flat data layout. However when it comes to fetching data, is it possible to use a similar method to multipath fetch data from multiple locations in Firebase?

For example I need to join some data together and my current code looks like this:

```
ref.child('data_1/').once('value', function (snapshot) {
    var test_string_1 = snapshot.val();

    ref.child('data_2/').once('value', function (snapshot) {
        var test_string_2 = snapshot.val();

        //...etc 
    });
});
```

When it comes to having to fetch data from multiple nodes, this nested approach goes quite deep. So I'd like to know if there is a better and faster method, like multipath fetching, to get data from multiple locations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the paths/refs are not dependent on each other, you can retrieve them like this:

```
var test_1 = ref.child('data_1/');
var test_2 = ref.child('data_2/');
Promise.all([
    test_1.once('value'),
    test_2.once('value')
]).then(function(snapshots) {
    var test_string_1 = snapshots[0].val();
    var test_string_2 = snapshots[1].val();
});
```

See:

- The [MDN documentation on `Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)
- [Speed up fetching posts for my social network app by using query instead of observing a single event repeatedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786)

Comment: Will I be able to dynamically pass a whole array of paths/refs to this method and fetch them in bulk?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786

Comment: I notice that when fetching a thousand records using this method, the load time is quite slow, up to 30 seconds of loading time sometimes for all data to be loaded. Is this normal?