# What is the C# equivalent to Promise.all?

Tags: c#, promise, task-parallel-library

I would like to fetch data from multiple locations from
Firebase Realtime Database like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43485344/4841380) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35932786/4841380) by Frank van Puffelen and I can't find any equivalent to `Promise.all` in c#. What would be the proper way to do it?

Comment: In addition to any answers here, check out [this SO answer explaining a Promise equivalent in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38998516/5803406)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That you are looking for is [Task.WhenAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netframework-4.7.2). You should create as many tasks as the multiple locations from which you want to fetch your data and then feed them in this method.

Comment: I think Task.WhenAll is similar to Promise.allSettled, not Promise.all. There is nothing in .NET similar to Promise.all as far as I know.

Comment: Here's [the example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17197786/283851) that probably should have come with this answer. As @Sake pointed out, this is more similar to `Promise.allSettled` than `Promise.all` - because of static typing, if you have `Task<T>` instances with different types `T`, something like `Promise.all` would lead you into type-casts, which is clunky and unsafe; you're better off with something like `Promise.allSettled` and simply await again for the results from the tasks that have already been run and resolved in parallel. It's all good. :-)

Answer (score 8):

To expand on @Christos's accepted answer:

[Task.WhenAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netframework-4.7.2) appears to be about as close as you will get for a drop-in replacement for [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). I actually found it to be closer than I initially thought. Here's an example using a JavaScript `Promise.all` implementation that you may want to replicate in C#:

```js
const [ resolvedPromiseOne, resolvedPromiseTwo ] = await Promise.all([ taskOne, taskTwo ]);
```

In C# you can do something very similar with `Task.WhenAll` (assuming they return the same types).

```cs
var taskList = new[]
{
  SomeTask(),
  AnotherTask()
};

var completedTasks = await Task.WhenAll(taskList);

// then access them like you would any array
var someTask = completedTasks[0];
var anotherTask = completedTasks[1];

// or just iterate over the array
foreach (var task in completedTasks)
{
  doSomething(task);
}
```

This assumes they're both in `async` methods / functions.

Comment: these seems to be either obsolete or for a earlier version of .NET than my env.

Comment: And what about when they don't return the same types?